# Style.css redirects to 404 Page not found

Tags: theme-development, themes

I've just uploaded a wordpress site from MAMP to a live site. Exactly the same methods I usually use to upload them, including permalinks and all the usual PHPMyAdmin bits.

This time the style.css, js and all the images are just redirecting to a 404 page.

The website is [here](http://www.kenchristy-ruralsupport.com/)

Can anyone help? This makes no sense at all.

EDIT: heres a snippit of header.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <!-- Version 1.0 of Ken Christys Rural Support Website -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' name='viewport'>
        <meta content='Josh Stevens, Lyndsay Hooper, PotatoMou.se' name='author'>
        <meta content='<?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?> ' name='description'>
        <meta content='' name='keywords'> 
        <script>
            if(!window.jQuery)
                {
                     var script = document.createElement('script');
                     script.type = "text/javascript";
                     script.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js";
                     document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
                }
        </script>


        <!-- Google Analytics-->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/javascript/pace.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />

        <title>
            <?php echo get_the_title() . "  -  ". get_bloginfo ( 'description' );  ?><br />
            <!-- Current Page title - Website description -->
        </title>



    </head>
```

and here is the actual rendered code:

```
<!---->
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <!-- Version 1.0 of Ken Christys Rural Support Website -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0' name='viewport'>
        <meta content='Josh Stevens, Lyndsay Hooper, PotatoMou.se' name='author'>
        <meta content='Ken Christy Rural Support ' name='description'>
        <meta content='' name='keywords'> 
        <script>
            if(!window.jQuery)
                {
                     var script = document.createElement('script');
                     script.type = "text/javascript";
                     script.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js";
                     document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
                }
        </script>


        <!-- Google Analytics-->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.kenchristy-ruralsupport.com/wp-content/themes/KenChristy/javascript/pace.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://www.kenchristy-ruralsupport.com/wp-content/themes/KenChristy/style.css" />

        <title>
            Home  -  Ken Christy Rural Support<br />
            <!-- Current Page title - Website description -->
        </title>
```

Comment: Did you flush your permalinks?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned originally, I've done all the usual bits.

Comment: What code is actually outputting the stylesheet that is returning the 404? Please post the relevant code from `header.php` or `functions.php`.

Comment: header.php - 
   <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/javascript/pace.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />

Comment: What happens when you delete google analytics. I feel that this is what is breaking your site. Have a look at this. `<script async="" src="//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script>` Your source is missing the `http:` part

Comment: Deleted it, still the same.

Comment: As @ChipBennett said, please post all relevant code for enqueueing scripts and stylesheets

Comment: As @PieterGoosen said: please **edit your question** to include the *code* that produces the output, as well as the *actual output* rendered by that code.

Comment: Done that, any further suggestions?

Comment: The real questions is, can you access anything in your theme folder by a direct link? It looks like anything / everything on that page that refers to your theme folder is 404. Double check that the spelling is correct and try to keep your theme folder name lowercase.

Comment: Simply put, no. The thing is I'm using Wordpress's own functions for the listing of these files. Why it won't work is baffling. I've just changed the theme folder name to lower case, still the same.

Comment: If paths are correct and you get WordPress 404s for existing physical files, you've got some sort of server configuration issue, your solution does not involve WordPress.

Comment: I've tried uploading it to a subdomain on a different site, same problem. What do you suggest?

Comment: What are the permissions for `wp-content/`, `wp-content/themes/`, and `wp-content/themes/KenChristy`? What happens if you rename your Theme folder from `KenChristy/` to `kenchristy/`?

Comment: Do you have any **core-bundled** Themes installed? If so, which ones?

Comment: wp-content: 0755, wp-content/themes: 0755, wp-content/themes/kenchristy: 0700. I changed it to lower case a little while ago. No themes installed.

Comment: "*`wp-content/themes/kenchristy`: `0700`*" - **HINT, HINT** One of these is not like the others... ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your directory permissions for your Theme directory are incorrect.

> - wp-content: 0755
> - wp-content/themes: 0755
> - wp-content/themes/kenchristy: 0700

[Per the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions#Shared_Hosting_with_suexec), folder permissions should be set to `755`:

In such an suexec configuration, the correct permissions scheme is simple to understand.

- All files should be owned by the actual user's account, not the user
  account used for the httpd process.
- Group ownership is irrelevant, unless there's specific group
  requirements for the web-server process permissions checking. This is
  not usually the case.
- **All directories should be 755 or 750.**
- All files should be 644 or 640. Exception: wp-config.php should be
  600 to prevent other users on the server from reading it.
- No directories should ever be given 777, even upload directories.
  Since the php process is running as the owner of the files, it gets
  the owners permissions and can write to even a 755 directory.

So, **try changing `wp-content/themes/kenchristy/` from `0700` to `0755`**.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" /
```

with

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>" />
```

also try placing your style above all your JS

Comment: Done, same problem, and it outputs the same: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.kenchristy-ruralsupport.com/wp-content/themes/KenChristy/style.css" />

Comment: I moved the code around as suggested, same same.

Comment: did you try to call it from functions.php? @Josh

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: wp_enqueue_style( 'THEMENAME-style', get_stylesheet_uri() ); @Josh

Comment: Nope, this does nothing.]

Comment: can you give me access to the backend so I can take a look? @Josh

Comment: Backend of WP or of the web server?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14047/discussion-between-bigant841-and-josh)

Comment: @bigant841 don't ask for backend info to a users site, never

Comment: when its sent to an email it is fine @PieterGoosen

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `wp_head` between `<head></head>` is missing. Just before `</head>` add `<?php wp_head(); ?>`Then, enqueue your scripts and stylesheets properly in your `functions.php`. Have a look at the following from the codex

[`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts)
[`wp_enqueue_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style)
[`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

Comment: Done, still no change.

Answer (score 0):

I had a folder named /CSS but was referencing /css in my enqueue.  This was no problem on local, but the URLs were case sensitive when I pushed it up to hosting