# Broken CSS after changing the site URL

Tags: migration, ip

I have a self-hosted Wordpress blog on my home server. Previously I accessed it directly via its original IP address taken from DHCP, but now I have configured a static IP address for it. The problem is that now all the CSS is broken.

I have updated my `wp-config.php` file adding the following two lines:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://192.168.0.100/myblog/');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://192.168.0.100/myblog/');
```

and I have restarted apache, but the CSS is still broken. Is there some other configuration file that I should update?

Comment: What are the addresses the stylesheets are being loaded from?

Comment: @s_ha_dum at the moment I am using the Twenty Thirteen theme and I haven't made any changes to it, so I would say everything is in the default theme folder.

Comment: Have you updated the keys that you mention in the `wp_options` DB table? WP may still be looking for some resources at the old IP address.

Comment: Didn't you change any file permissions. There was a similiar question on this [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141962/style-css-redirects-to-404-page-not-found/141969#141969)

Comment: @DavidGard I haven't, but is it necessary? This page from the Codex seems to say that my edit should be enough: http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: @PieterGoosen Nope, only changed the machine's IP address.

Comment: Ah, the article states - "**Note**: Both settings should include the http:// part and ***should not have a slash "/" at the end***." Your entries above do have a slash at the end, meaning the URL to your style-sheet will be in the format of `http://192.168.0.100/myblog//wp-content/themes/my-theme/style.css'

Comment: I didn't ask where everything actually is. I asked what the address of the request is. Look at the page source, find the reference to your stylsheet(s), and paste the URL(s) into the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For some reason, changing the URL from the GUI worked (after restoring the machine to the old IP address). Go figure.

Answer (score 6):

If you have access to your mysql you can update the `wp-options` table.

Before modification...

```
$ mysql -u <db_user> --password=<db_pwd> -D <db_name> <<<"select * from wp_options where option_name in ('siteurl', 'home');"
+-----------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| option_id | option_name     | option_value                                                                                      | autoload |
+-----------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|         1 | siteurl         | http://172.17.0.2/wordpress                                                                       | yes      |
|         2 | home            | http://172.17.0.2/wordpress                                                                       | yes      |
+-----------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
```

Then I changed the ip to 172.17.0.4 with this...

```
$ mysql mysql -u <db_user> --password=<db_pwd> -D <db_name> <<<"update wp_options set option_value='http://172.17.0.4/wordpress' where option_name in ('siteurl', 'home');"
```

So the table becomes...

```
+-----------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| option_id | option_name     | option_value                                                                                      | autoload |
+-----------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|         1 | siteurl         | http://172.17.0.4/wordpress                                                                       | yes      |
|         2 | home            | http://172.17.0.4/wordpress                                                                       | yes      |
+-----------+-----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
```

In some scenarios it could be useful to automatically update this configuration.

Comment: This worked for me. Along with this I also changed url in the GUI

Answer (score 0):

The WordPress Codex '[Changing The Site URL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL)' states the following -

> Note: Both settings should include the http:// part and should not have a slash "/" at the end.

I notice in your question that both the `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` constants include the trailing slash. This means that the URL to your style-sheet will be in this format -

```
http://192.168.0.100/myblog//wp-content/themes/my-theme/style.css'
```

In short, remove the trailing slash from both declarations and it should fix the problem.

Note also that the aforementioned Codex states the following in relation to the solution that you have chosen.

> This is not necessarily the best fix, it's just hardcoding the values into the site itself. You won't be able to edit them on the General settings page anymore when using this method.

I suggest using one of the other more permanent methods described to achieve your goal.

Comment: Double slashes, though technically incorrect, still tend to work-- tested in five different browsers. I doubt this the problem.

Comment: @s_ha_dum - It depends on whether or not the URL has been rewritten. If it has, double slashes can still work (although not ideal). If not, essentially you are looking for a directory listing, so double slashes will not work.

Comment: Stylesheet URLs are _not_ rewritten, not by Core anyway, and that is exactly what I tested with-- I sent a direct request to the stylesheet URL. But I cannot find any combination of slashes that breaks requests on my server for any page, with or without permalinks (aka URL rewriting). If you know of some specific reproducible circumstances, please elaborate.

Comment: @s_ha_dum - I realise the stylesheet URL would not be broken, hence my reference to non-rewritten URLs. I'll do some testing now, as I'm sure I've come across issues with double slashes in the past...

Comment: @s_ha_dum - Well I can't get double slashes to break my test site, so I guess I must have imagined that... However, my answer is still technically correct ;-)

Comment: Yep, I tried this and it didn't work either. However, for some weird reason, after restoring the blog to its old IP address and changing the URL from the GUI, now it works. Go figure

Answer (score 0):

Migrating your WordPress site to another location should be a painless process: you just have to export your database, import it to the new host, move your files there, configure everything and make the new site live. However, there are some steps that, when not done right, could provoke several problems that cause trouble and lead to unsuccessful site transfers.

Answer (score -1):

For any reason my site URL had an extra space at the end of the line in the DB - wp-options